# Reads/Writes/Formats for Non Case Class in Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization

I know how to serialize a case class in Scala with the simple

```
implicit val caseClassFormat = Json.format[CaseClass]
```

However, I can't seem to find how to serialize a regular class. How does this work? I know that I have to extend Serializable. But, then when I try to run `Json.toJson(class)` my compiler throws an error saying that I need to write an implicit reads/writes.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Json.format[X]` call runs a macro in play that creates the `Format[X]` code for you.

If you look at the implementation of the Macro, it requires that an `unapply` and `apply` function exist within the companion object of the class that is provided. With a case class, both of these things are true.

If you want to be able to use the shorthand for formatters, then you can do the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

class Foo(val s: String)

object Foo{
  def apply(s: String) = new Foo(s)
  def unapply(f: Foo) = Some(f.s)
}

val format = Json.format[Foo]
```

This will allow you to serialize, deserialize the JSON accordingly.

```
val asString = Json.toJson(Foo("hello"))(format).toString
val js = Json.parse(asString).as[Foo](format)
```